# How can I create this view in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I know how to create the settings button on the side, but I am not sure how to create the box that has the settings. Can someone guide me ? [image]

Answer (score 1):

try `$ionicPopover`

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopover/